# Using a right-exact functor to show isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm working on a homework problem which asks me to show that $A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_m \cong A/mA$ for any abelian group $A$. We are also given a hint to explore right exactness of the tensor product. However, I can't see at all why this hint is relevant. I have no idea how one could derive an isomorphism from an exact sequence. A push in the right direction would be really helpful.

Comment: Right exactness means preservation of cokernels: $\operatorname{coker} (A\otimes B\to A\otimes C) \cong A\otimes \operatorname{coker} (B\to C)$. Now $\mathbb{Z}_m$ (also known as $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$) is the cokernel of some homomorphism...

Comment: Note that $\mathbb Z\otimes A\cong A$.

Comment: Ah! I've been using the functor $T: B \to B\otimes\mathbb{Z}_m$. I'll go work with that and see what I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: Abelian groups are Z modules

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the first hint above, I figured it out. For anyone else working on this, consider the sequence $\mathbb{Z}\overset{f}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\overset{\pi}{\to}\mathbb{Z}_m\to 0$ with the appropriate rule of assignment for $f$ which makes the sequence exact. Utilize right exactness of the tensor product with $A$ and the first isomorphism theorem to derive $A/mA\cong (A\otimes\mathbb{Z})/(mA\otimes\mathbb{Z})\cong A\otimes\mathbb{Z}_m$.